# How to look for paths described as regular expression in a (networkx) graph?

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, graph-algorithm, networkx

Given a directed possibly cyclic networkx graph. I would like to search for paths which are described as a regular expression. The regexes will not describe cycles. An example would be:

```
nodeA, [^nodeB]* [nodeC|nodeD]
```

In english this should correspond to: I am looking for a path starting with nodeA,followed by zero, one or many nodes which are not nodeB, and finally the path should end with either nodeC or nodeD.

Example paths I would like to find would be:

- nodeA->nodeX->nodeC
- nodeA->nodeX->nodeY->nodeD
- nodeA->nodeC
- ...

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682131/find-all-paths-in-directed-cyclic-graph-as-regular-expression) related post on SO. Yet, it is about creating a regex from all possible paths between two nodes. In my case, I provide a regex and would like to get the corresponding paths.

My incomplete (and probably insufficient) approach is this:

1. Split the regex-described path up into parts starting with a single fixed node and ending with a single fixed node. Single fixed node means `some_node` (i.e. no special regex characters such as [],^, *, + etc.).
2. Search for this path using regular networkx functionality
3. If a path is found, I go through it node by node and look at the "current" regex part (starting at the beginning of the regex).
4. If the current regex part is a `[^some_node]` then I check if the current node is equal to that. I break if it is equal and advance the node and the regex part if not.
5. If the current regex part is a some_node , i.e. the node `some_node` must be there then I check if the current node is equal to that. If it is, I advance the node and the regex. If not, I only advance the node.

Before writing more code for the other cases, e.g. `[some_node]*` or `[some_node]+` I wanted to check if there exists some code or algorithm for this task already.

**Is there any read-to-use module/lib/sample code or the like for this task ?** 

**If not, do you know of an existing algorithm "regex to path search in graph"?**

**If not, could you outline an algorithm ?**

Comment: You should checkout [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/). It is a graph NoSQL database that uses [CQL](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) (Cypher Query Language). It pretty much is a form of specifying regex for paths. Maybe it will give you some insights.

Comment: @cenouro : Excellent hint, thanks. After having read a bit about graph databases, I am wondering if CQL or gremlin is better suited for my problem. What do you think?

Comment: I have never heard about Gremlim, so I can't give my opinion. Also, I haven't used Neo4j, only read the docs and done some tutorials. They seem to be a solid choice for you, but YMMV. Another lib you might be interested is [igraph](http://igraph.org/redirect.html). It is widely adopted by Python devs and depending on the size of your graphs, Neo4j/Gremlim may be overkill.

Comment: @cenouro Thanks for the pointer to igraph.